# Handler Runnable runs even after activity exit

Tags: android, runnable, android-handler

I am updating the text user types in a textview to database every 5 seconds.
The handler collects data from textview and save it to database.
But the update code runs even after I press back button and return to MainActivity.

How can I stop running the code after exiting from activity.

```
  public class CreateBoxActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Long current_BoxID  = null, parent_BoxID = null;
    Handler h=new Handler();

       @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_box);
        h.post(new Runnable(){ //Run this every five seconds to update the data
            @Override
            public void run() {

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                String editeddate = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                String titleText =  ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_box_title)).getText().toString();
                String descriText =  ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_box_descri)).getText().toString();
                Boxes nbx = new Boxes(1, null , titleText, descriText, editeddate, editeddate);
                BoxesController.UpdateBox(nbx);

                h.postDelayed(this,5000);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the handler in onPause

```
Runnable  runnable =new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {

      }
    };
    new Handler().removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to release the handler resource when the activity is destroyed.

```
@override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    h.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    h = null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create runnable outside of the method like :

```
Runnable  runnable =new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {

  }
};
```

On your activity's `onPause` call:

```
h.removeCallback(runnable);
```